# Error when importing a module

Tags: powershell, module

I am creating a useful powershell module for myself, for repetitive tasks.

As an example I will use one function within the module.

```
function GetUserInfo
{
    $user_name = $env:UserName
    $user_domain = $env:UserDomain
    $user_computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $user_ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($user_computer);
    $user_ip = $user_ip[1].IPAddressToString

    return $user_info = "$user_domain/$user_ip/$user_computer/$user_name"
}
export-modulemember -function GetUserInfo
```

Every time I try to load the module

```
Import-Module \\erpscriptprod\Library\PowerShell\PowerShell_BaseLibrary.ps1
```

I get the followoing error...

> The Export-ModuleMember cmdlet can only be called from inside a module

I am new to powershell, but from where I'm sitting, I swear I am calling it inside the module. I can't seem to find the error online, but I doubt I'm the only person to experience this.

Comment: `PowerShell_BaseLibrary.ps1` -> `PowerShell_BaseLibrary.psm1`

Comment: @BenH I'm sorry I'm not sure I follow. when I import?

Comment: `.ps1` is not a module file. Rename your script.

Comment: Oh wow ... Thank you. I guess it's time for coffee. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename your *.ps1 file to *.psm1. You can only export members from a module, when you call `Export-ModuleMember`.